# jQuery live filter on a table with multiple input fieds / search criteria?

Tags: jquery, filter

I have used the jQuery live filter on my website as per 
http://chris-spittles.co.uk/jquery-filter-table/

This works wonderfully well. My client has since asked that I have three inputs which can filter the data. They would all work together to filter the table.

I have setup a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/NVL5h/5/

My desired result is that in filter 1 I could type books, in filter 2 I could then type in a date. now the table would only show results that have `type OR date` in them that match the filter inputs. Similarly I would like to type a book name in filter 3 so now I can search for table results that have

'Type **OR** date **or** BookName'

Is this possible with the script I have or perhaps is there another script that caters for this requirements already? I am sure it is, just unsure how. I did try tinker a little but without success. The fiddle works as per design, I have just added the additional input fields that I would like to filter on.

Comment: would take considerable refactoring of script. Might take a look at datatables. Has huge API and is far more robust than script you currently have. Has ability to extend with custom filters. No matter what will likely have to write own filter for the `or` conditions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to give the datatables jquery plugin a try.   It should do just about any thing you are looking for with table management

https://datatables.net/

I took your fiddler example and made a few changes with the datatable.js file in use to do multiple column filtering.

http://jsfiddle.net/M2mUF/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('.liveFilterList').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        }
    });

    $("tfoot input").keyup(function () {
        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
        oTable.fnFilter(this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this));
    });

   /*
    * Support functions to provide a little bit of 'user friendlyness' to the textboxes in 
    * the footer
    */
   $("tfoot input").each(function (i) {
       asInitVals[i] = this.value;
   });

   $("tfoot input").focus(function () {
       if (this.className == "search_init") {
           this.className = "";
           this.value = "";
       }
   });

   $("tfoot input").blur(function (i) {
       if (this.value == "") {
           this.className = "search_init";
           this.value = asInitVals[$("tfoot input").index(this)];
       }
   });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Dude, that is epic. thanks a million, made my day :-)